# Can not PUT, POST, DELETE http method in PHP rest api

Tags: javascript, php, docker, rest, composer-php

my api follow source path Src/Api/Notes/index.php:

```
   <?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
    // TODO
    } elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    // TODO
    } elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'PUT') {
    // TODO
    } elseif ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'DELETE') {
    // TODO
    } else {
    // TODO echo error
    }
```

URL that I use is localhost/api/notes, When I use HTTP GET, it happens normally. But when I use Post, Put, delete, $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] received is always Get.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
    RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
     RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
     RewriteRule ^api/(.*)$ src/api/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Help me, thank you

I tried changing the filename other than the index.php name then the http method worked properly.
Thanks you

Comment: Does URL `localhost/api/notes` automatically redirects to `localhost/api/notes/` (with / at the end) ?

Comment: What happens if you try to disable `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php` from `.htaccess` file?

Comment: Are you sure this problem is in any way related to Javascript, Docker, or Composer? Please share more details, especially your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Please add how you are sending these test requests with other methods. If you are using curl, please show `curl --verbose ...` output.